# Create Time Countdown in Javascript

Tags: javascript

Iam creating a workout countdown timer using javascript.

This is my code

```js
var counter = 30;

setInterval( function(){
  counter--;

  if( counter >= 0 ){
    id = document.getElementById("count");
    id.innerHTML = counter;
  }

  if( counter === 0 ){
    id.innerHTML = "REST";
  }
}, 1000);
```

```html
<div class="container">
      <h1 id="count">WORK</h1>
</div>
```

The time countdown running well, but i want to add a rest time countdown after 30sec workout.

Please Help me Thanks...

Comment: You need to stop the setInterval(). below id.innerHTML = "REST", add a new line clearInterval(this) so that it stops the interval and also add another line below it setTimeout() to wait for 30sec rest break. After that last (3rd line) would be restart the interval.

Comment: how is the code will be? im really new on javascript.. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code should work. Once the workout `counter` reaches 0, we can switch to rest mode and rest for 30 seconds (you can change how long the user rests for as well). After these 30 seconds are up, the timer will switch back into workout mode and the loop continues.

Edit: We can create a variable `rounds` and increment this variable every time we go into Workout Mode. Once `rounds` reaches the value of 11, we can use `clearInterval()` to stop the code, after setting the `setInterval(function(){},1000)` to a variable called `interval`.

```js
var counter = 30;
var mode = "Workout";
var rounds = 1;

var interval = setInterval( function(){
  counter--;

  if(mode == "Workout" && counter >= 0 ){
    id = document.getElementById("count");
    id.innerHTML = "Workout Number " + rounds + ": " + counter;
  }
  else{
    id = document.getElementById("count");
    id.innerHTML = "Rest: " + counter;
  }

  if( counter === 0 ){
    if(mode == "Workout"){
       mode = "Rest";
    }
    else{
       mode = "Workout";
       rounds++;
    }
    id.innerHTML = "REST";
    counter = 30;
    if (rounds == 11){
      clearInterval(interval);
    }
  }
}, 1000);
```

```html
<div class="container">
      <h1 id="count">WORK</h1>
</div>
```

I hope this helped! Let me know if you need any further details or clarification :)

Comment: Why not clearInterval

Comment: I thought OP wants a "rest time" after the workout?

Comment: Rest countdown...

Comment: Ohhh oops i misread question let me edit ty

Comment: Thanks it gave what i want sir.. and 1 more question if i may ask, how to end the workout after 10 rounds? Thanks

Comment: ooh good question hold on let me edit response

Comment: Okay, I think I did it! Let me know if this is what you wanted, or if you have any questions :)

Answer (score 0):

You should put the id outside of current scope, and also clear interval:

```
var counter = 30;

var intervalId = setInterval( function(){
  counter--;
  var id = document.getElementById("count");

  if( counter >= 0 ){
    id.innerHTML = counter;
  }

  if( counter === 0 ){
    id.innerHTML = "REST";
    clearInterval(intervalId)
  }
}, 1000);
```

Comment: Why no restart?

Answer (score 0):

You can have a function which accepts `trainingTime` aswell as `restTime` and display one of them conditionally on every interval.

```js
function startTraining(trainingTime, restTime) {

    const fullTime = trainingTime + restTime
    var counter = 0

    const display = (value) => {
        id = document.getElementById("count");
        id.innerHTML = value;
    }

    // display the start time immediatly!.
    display('TRAIN: ' + fullTime)

    const interval = setInterval(function () {
        counter++;


        // stop training if fulltime is reached/exceeded
        if (counter >= fullTime) {
            clearInterval(interval)
            display('training ended')
            // start next training here!.  
            // ...        
        }

        else {
            // calculate remaining time
            const remainingTime = fullTime - counter

            // Display "TRAIN" if counter is less than needed trainingTime 
            // else display "REST"
            const keyword = counter < trainingTime ? 'TRAIN' : 'REST'

            // update html:
            display(keyword + ': ' + remainingTime)
        }

}, 1000);
}

const trainingTime = 15
const restTime = 15
startTraining(trainingTime, restTime)
```

```html
<div class="container">
      <h1 id="count">WORK</h1>
</div>
```

With above snippet you can also know the exact moment a training ended.

Comment: how to make rest time will be counting down as well? Thanks